# Given path format not supported c#

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I get this exception when trying to perform an XSLT transformation with C#:

```
Exception: System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.QuickDemand(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String fullPath, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath)    
   at System.Xml.XmlResolver.ResolveUri(Uri baseUri, String relativeUri)
   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.ResolveUri(Uri baseUri, String relativeUri)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String url, XmlNameTable nt)
   at System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument..ctor(String uri, XmlSpace space)
   at System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument..ctor(String uri)
   at ConsoleApplication8.Program.TransformXML(String sXmlPath, String sXslPath)
```

when i try to run this code

```
 void test()
 {
     var myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
     myXslTrans.Load(@"‪C:\Users\ahmed\Desktop\fewf\visio.xsl");
     myXslTrans.Transform(@"‪C:\Users\ahmed\Desktop\fewf\page1.xml", @"‪C:\Users\ahmed\Desktop\fewf\page.html"); 
 }
```

i try to use `Path.Combine();`  but give me the same case 
How can i solve this ?

Comment: What line throws the exception? Is the exception based on the line in the code above, or is the exception thrown by a path used inside XSLT (remember that in XSLT the path must be URI).

Comment: `System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.QuickDemand(FileIOPermissionA
ccess access, String fullPath, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath)

   at System.Xml.XmlResolver.ResolveUri(Uri baseUri, String relativeUri)
   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.ResolveUri(Uri baseUri, String relativeUri)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String url, XmlNameTable nt)
   at System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument..ctor(String uri, XmlSpace space)
   at System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument..ctor(String uri)
   at ConsoleApplication8.Program.TransformXML(String sXmlPath, String sXslPath)`

Comment: @Abel, it doesn't look exact duplicate to me.

Comment: You are getting the error mostly because of the path `C:\Users\ahmed` which your program may not have access to. Try placing the file in a separate directory and it should work fine.

Comment: @Abel , the name of error is the same as i mentioned above 
`Exception: System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supporte
d.
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.QuickDemand(FileIOPermissionA
ccess access, String fullPath, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath)`
The full exception can't be wrote in comment

Comment: @Rahul  after replace at `@"‪E:\fci\s\page1.xml"` i got the same error

Comment: @MiDo_FCIcu, thanks. I just updated my answer (see bottom half), it looks like I wasn't looking at this from the right angle.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it was not clear from your question that you are using Silverlight (or at least some platform that somehow triggers this method)). When I started searching for `QuickDemand`, it turned out that this is only called in SilverLight (or similar?) environments, so I am rewriting my answer with that in mind.

> ```
> at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.QuickDemand
> ```

This error is caused by [this block of code in the reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/permissions/fileiopermission.cs,c5f316b1d4e58374). As can be seen there, if the path contains a colon above second position, it is considered invalid.

In your code above this isn't shown, but since this is the only place in the reference source where this specific error is thrown, I am going to assume that the *real* code you have (possibly any of the `xsl:include`s in the XSLT) is containing a colon at some position other than the second position.

Either way, if this doesn't help, go to the Exceptions screen and check the NotSupportedException and in the Debug window uncheck the "Just my code" and check the "Enable .NET framework source stepping". That way, you can break at the position where the error is thrown and use IntelliSense and the debug windows to find out the context (i.e. the actual path) that is causing this error.

Also, from my previous post, if this doesn't help:

- Try your code with a minimal XSLT (this is vital!)
- Once you have that running, add an `xsl:include`
- Once you have that running, add a `document` (if you use that, in addition, enable it in the settings)
- Once you have that running... well, you get the drift

Comment: @MiDo_FCIcu, also, can you check if you have any paths inside your XSLT stylesheet, i.e. `xsl:import`, `document()` (which is disabled by default) or `xsl:include`?

Comment: Yes 
`<xsl:include href="style.xsl"/>
  <xsl:include href="text.xsl"/>
  <xsl:include href="masters.xsl"/>
  <xsl:include href="nurbs.xsl"/>`
This file in the same path

Comment: @MiDo_FCIcu ok, can you then try create a minimal (i.e., empty) XSLT file and check if that works? Then add one include, then another. We need to find the exact cause of your error. Also, really check your rights, open your program as Administrator, see if that helps. See the four steps I pointed out.

Comment: @MiDo_FCIcu: I did a quick check in .NET Reflector and the `QuickDemand` method does not exist in .NET 4.0. What platform are you using? What version of .NET? Is it possible that you are using SilverLight?

Comment: @MiDo_FCIcu, I'm afraid that all the information you have given is too little to give a good answer, but I have rewritten my answer, perhaps it helps. If not, please create a minimal example that we can use to replicate your behavior, otherwise it will remain a guessing game: [mcve].